# javascript effect is not correct

Tags: javascript, mootools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shaojie.me/wp-content/example/styles/base.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shaojie.me/wp-content/example/styles/item.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mootools-core-1.3.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="main-content-full">
    <iframe id="resize" src="buy.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The inner iframe page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shaojie.me/wp-content/example/styles/base.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shaojie.me/wp-content/example/styles/item.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://shaojie.me/wp-content/example/scripts/mootools-core-1.3.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="main-content-full">
<div class="main-content-row species">
<div class="bd">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>
        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=110000">
            女装/女士精品：</a>
    </th>

    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110800&amp;Q=">
                连衣裙</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110400&amp;Q=">
                T恤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=111800&amp;Q=">
                裤子</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=111700&amp;Q=">
                春夏装</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110500&amp;Q=">
                衬衫</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=112300&amp;Q=">
                蕾丝衫/雪纺衫</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=111900&amp;Q=">
                半身裙</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110100&amp;Q=">
                针织衫</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=112200&amp;Q=">
                小背心/小吊带</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110600&amp;Q=">
                小西装</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110900&amp;Q=">
                皮衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110300&amp;Q=">
                短外套</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=112800&amp;Q=">
                婚纱/旗袍/礼服</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=112400&amp;Q=">
                牛仔裤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=112900&amp;Q=">
                马夹</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=111500&amp;Q=">
                羽绒服</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110700&amp;Q=">
                卫衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=111600&amp;Q=">
                羽绒背心/棉背心</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=110200&amp;Q=">
                毛衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=111400&amp;Q=">
                棉衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=111100&amp;Q=">
                风衣</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <th>
        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=100000">
            男装：</a>
    </th>
    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=100400&amp;Q=">
                长袖衬衫</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=100300&amp;Q=">
                长袖T恤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=100500&amp;Q=">
                休闲长裤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=101000&amp;Q=">
                牛仔裤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=101100&amp;Q=">
                卫衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=100100&amp;Q=">
                羽绒服</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=100900&amp;Q=">
                西服</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=100800&amp;Q=">
                毛衣/线衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=100700&amp;Q=">
                风衣</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>

        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=180000">
            童装/亲子装：</a>
    </th>
    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=181000&amp;Q=">
                儿童T恤/吊带衫</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=180600&amp;Q=">
                儿童裙子</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=180100&amp;Q=">
                儿童套装</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=181300&amp;Q=">
                儿童裤子</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=180400&amp;Q=">
                儿童毛衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=181200&amp;Q=">
                儿童衬衫</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=181500&amp;Q=">
                其它童装</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=180800&amp;Q=">
                长裤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=180300&amp;Q=">
                儿童卫衣/绒衫</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>
        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=160000">
            女鞋：</a>

    </th>
    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=160300&amp;Q=">
                帆布鞋</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>
        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=170000">
            服饰配件：</a>

    </th>
    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=170200&amp;Q=">
                腰带/皮带/腰链</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=171200&amp;Q=">
                其它配件</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=170100&amp;Q=">
                帽子</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <th>
        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=150000">
            男鞋：</a>
    </th>
    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150300&amp;Q=">
                休闲皮鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150200&amp;Q=">
                运动休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150100&amp;Q=">
                日常休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=151600&amp;Q=">
                凉拖</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150900&amp;Q=">
                商务休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=151300&amp;Q=">
                懒人鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150300&amp;Q=">
                休闲皮鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150200&amp;Q=">
                运动休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150100&amp;Q=">
                日常休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=151600&amp;Q=">
                凉拖</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150900&amp;Q=">
                商务休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=151300&amp;Q=">
                懒人鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150300&amp;Q=">
                休闲皮鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150200&amp;Q=">
                运动休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150100&amp;Q=">
                日常休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=151600&amp;Q=">
                凉拖</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=150900&amp;Q=">
                商务休闲鞋</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=151300&amp;Q=">
                懒人鞋</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>

        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=190000">
            家居鞋类：</a>
    </th>
    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=190100&amp;Q=">
                拖鞋</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>

        <a href="BuyerList.aspx?cat=120000">
            内衣/家居服：</a>
    </th>
    <td>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=120700&amp;Q=">
                男士内裤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=120100&amp;Q=">
                文胸</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=120200&amp;Q=">
                女士内裤</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=120400&amp;Q=">
                保暖内衣</a></li>

            <li><a href="BuyerList.aspx?Cat=122300&amp;Q=">
                短袜/打底袜/丝袜/静脉曲张袜</a></li>

        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">more</a>
    </td>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*products species*/
    var itemMore = {
        initialize: function() {
            this.uls = $$(".species ul");
            this.mores = $$(".species .more");
            this.mores.each(function(more, i) {
                this.toggleItem(more, this.uls[i], i);
            }, this)
        },

        toggleItem: function(more, ul, i) {
            ul.setStyle("height", "auto");
            if (ul.getSize().y > 18) {
                var store = true;
                ul.setStyle("height", "18px")
            }
            if (!store) {
                more.setStyle("display", "none");
            }
            more.addEvent("click", function(e) {
                e.stop();
                this.toggleClass("up");
                ul.toggleClass("item");
            })
        }
    }
    itemMore.initialize();

    top.$("resize").set({
                styles: {
                    width: 760,
                    height: 1200
                }
            })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The question demo page links is:** http://shaojie.me/wp-content/example/home.php

The fifth row should not display the more (更多) button, but it's displayed. Can anyone help to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the fifth row's "more" button is being displayed because the height of the `<ul>` is more than 18 pixels, even though there is only one horizontal line of text in that row.

If I navigate directly to http://shaojie.me/wp-content/example/buy.php, I don't see the problem.

Perhaps you should use a larger threshold, like

```
// ...
if (ul.getSize().y > 24) {
    var store = true;
    ul.setStyle("height", "18px")
}
// ...
```

Or, use a "smarter" test — one that doesn't rely on the height of the `<ul>`. How about counting the number of `<li>`s? Assuming 4 columns of `<li>`s, then,

```
// ...
if (ul.getElements("li").length > 4) {
    var store = true;
    ul.setStyle("height", "18px")
}
// ...
```

Comment: But why i get the fifth row's height of <ul> is 54px? it's not 18px

Comment: I don't know - I wasn't able to put a breakpoint in the script (to debug it) since the script is inline, not in an external JS file.